# Formatting in cpp

Tags: c++, c++11, formatting

There is certain part of the code in my program that produces a result in contrast to the wanted.

I have to print the time (expected and scheduled) about many entries. I need each time parameter to be printed exactly at the same position as the previous. As well, when given time is, for example, 8:30 it needs to be translated to 08:30

This is my code so far. (overloaded << operator to work with my class, out is the ostream ref, l is reference to a class object)

```
if(l.get_hour() < 10 || l.get_minute() < 10)
{
    if(!(l.get_minute() < 10) && l.get_hour() < 10)
    {
        out << "0" << l.get_hour() << ":" << l.get_minute();
    }
    else if(l.get_minute() < 10 && !(l.get_hour() < 10))
        out << l.get_hour() << ":" << "0" << l.get_minute();
    else if(l.get_minute() < 10 && l.get_hour() < 10)
        out << "0" << l.get_hour() << ":" << "0" << l.get_minute();
}
else
    out << l.get_hour() << ":" << l.get_minute();
return out;
```

Everything works alright until I print the formatted the output.

```
cout << right << setw(5) << entry[0].get_expected() << setw(5) << entry[0].get_scheduled() << endl;
cout << right << setw(5) << entry[9].get_expected() << setw(5) << entry[9].get_scheduled() << endl;
```

Which after printing produces the time data with some dislocation.

So, my question is where is this coming from and how can it be fixed?

The output is as follows

```
14:45 15:50
 08:50  09:20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that there are a couple of space first and then the rest of the output? That's because the `setw` manipulator only works on the *next* output to the stream.

You don't actually *need* to set the field width, as you will always print out five characters (if the overloaded function works as it should).

Alternatively you could format the time to a `ostringstream` and use that string to do a single output to the actual output stream.

Comment: It produces the same output.